# How to use Camera in flutter Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, camera

I want to use the camera in the flutter windows and also has a library for Android but not for Windows. I did not get any results from Google.

Comment: Check this PR on github: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/4641

Comment: thank you. I solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my system drivers, and after updating the drivers, the problem was fixed and the program worked without any problems.